# zoom to search feature in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I created an openlayers map and used bootstrap search control. After clicking the search button the map is going to feature zoom extent but again the whole map is refreshing.
Below is the source code I wrote...

```
<div class="input-group add-on">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text" onkeypress="autoFill()"/>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="searchStateName();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>

function searchStateName() {

    input = document.getElementById("srch-term").value.toUpperCase();

    if (input) {
        for (var i = 0; i < countryData.length; i++) {
            //alert(countryData[0]);
            if (countryData[i].P.name_1.toUpperCase() == input) {
                alert(countryData[i].P.name_1);
                var extent = countryData[i].P.geom.getExtent();
                map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());

                if (countryData[i] !== highlight) {
                    if (highlight) {
                        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
                    }
                    if (countryData[i]) {
                        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(countryData[i]);
                    }
                    highlight = countryData[i];
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me find where is the problem

Comment: what about running example so that your question follows https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your code in loop:

```
if (countryData[i] !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (countryData[i]) {
        featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(countryData[i]);
    }
    highlight = countryData[i];
}
```

`hightlight` is a common variable, isn't it? It always preserve the last created feature. But you **remove previous created feature every time in the loop** that the map will have just one feature at the end.